# Element wise multiplication of first 4 columns by last 4 columns

Tags: r

I'm trying to do an element wise multiplication of the first 2 columns by the next 2 columns and add the result on the fifth column

for example :

```
> x = diag(4)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]   C1*C3 + C2*C4
[1,]    1    0    0    0   1*0 + 0*0 
[2,]    0    1    0    0   0*0 + 1*0 
[3,]    0    0    1    0   0*1 +0*0
[4,]    0    0    0    1   0*0 +0*1
```

Thank you!

Comment: You get all 0's anyways.  One option is `library(matrixStats);rowProds(x[,c(TRUE, FALSE)]) + rowProds(x[,c(FALSE, TRUE)])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this pretty directly in base R.

```
cbind(x, rowSums(x[,1:2] * x[,3:4]))
```

Although going by what you show in your 'results' you are doing every other column which is a simple modification

```
cbind(x, rowSums(x[,c(1,3)] * x[,c(2,4)]))
```

Comment: @lapioche75 you're welcome, please be sure to accept the answer if you are satisfied